# Find factorial in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table which has a column call numbers

```
Numbers
------
3
5
```

I am trying to get the factorial of those. I am using the below logic but not with proper result

```
Select 
    Numbers
    ,EXP(SUM(LN(Numbers)) OVER (ORDER BY Numbers)) Factorial 
FROM testTbl
```

**Output
**

```
Numbers Factorial
------  ---------
3   3.00000000000000000000000000000000000001
5   15.0000000000000000000000000000000000002
```

What is wrong? Please help

```
Expected
--------

Numbers Factorial
------  ---------
3   6
5   120
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at [this article](http://www.club-oracle.com/articles/how-to-get-factorial-in-oracle-159/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a go at this from another angle, trying to do it all in a SQL statement (using your table testTbl and the column numbers).

This is what I've come up with, see if it suits you:

```
  SELECT testtbl.numbers,
         ROUND( EXP( SUM( LN( t1.n ) ) ) ) AS factorial
    FROM (    SELECT UNIQUE LEVEL n
                FROM testtbl
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= numbers) t1,
         (    SELECT UNIQUE LEVEL n
                FROM testtbl
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= numbers) t2,
         testTbl
   WHERE t1.n <= t2.n
     AND t2.n = testTbl.numbers
   GROUP BY testtbl.numbers
   ORDER BY testtbl.numbers;
```

Gives the output:

> ```
> Numbers Factorial
> 3       6  
> 5       120
> ```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Were it me, I'd create a factorial function and call that user-defined function in my query.  Something like

```
SQL> create function factorial( p_n in number )
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    if( p_n = 1 )
  6    then
  7      return p_n;
  8    else
  9      return p_n * factorial( p_n - 1 );
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> with t as (
  2    select 3 num from dual
  3    union all
  4    select 5 from dual
  5  )
  6  select num,
  7         factorial(num)
  8    from t;

       NUM FACTORIAL(NUM)
---------- --------------
         3              6
         5            120
```

If for some reason you cannot define a new function and you really want to do it in SQL, you'll can generate all the numbers less than the number in your table and then aggregate those generated numbers.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 3 num from dual
  3    union all
  4    select 5 from dual
  5  )
  6  select t.num,
  7         exp( sum(ln(gen.num))) factorial
  8    from (select level num
  9            from dual
 10         connect by level <= (select max(t.num) from t)) gen,
 11         t
 12   where gen.num <= t.num
 13*  group by t.num
SQL> /

       NUM  FACTORIAL
---------- ----------
         5        120
         3          6
```